# Setup Payment Gateway from Europe

Tags: payments, payment-gateway

I'm from Europe and i want buy some payment gateway for internet credit/debit card processing.

I have a problem because PayPal and Authorize.net solutions is best but only from US and Canada users.

What Europe Payment Gateway you recommend me? I can use US PayPal when i not in US? Is some workaround?

I'm from Poland.

Greetings

Comment: Your options will be limited and most likely not priced anywhere near what Paypal and Authorize.Net charge.

Comment: @john: fixed;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorize.Net is only available in the US as it only works with US based merchant accounts so that rules them out.

Paypal does offer its services in Poland so they definitely are an option for you.

The third best option is probably Worldpay. Their rates seem to be the most competitive outside of the US and Paypal.

Comment: payflow gateway and payflow link is available only to US, Canada, New zeland, Australia;-/

Comment: Correct. But they have other APIs that are available to you in Poland.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the country, as most European countries have their own established credit card processing firms.  These local providers have various advantages in their respective core markets, such as providing service in the local language, supporting local cards and other payment methods that may not be widely used in other regions, easy compliance with local regulations and customer trust through local brand recognition.

For example, [Luottokunta](http://www.luottokunta.fi/en) (the Finnish Credit Union) has a nearly 100% market share here in Finland.  They do offer services outside Finland too, but even there they seem to be mostly focusing on the Nordic and Baltic regions.

I'm sure there are such local providers in Poland too.  A quick Google search for [*credit card processing poland*](http://www.google.com/search?q=credit+card+processing+poland) turned up at least [eCard S.A.](http://www.ecard.pl/credit-card-processing-online.htm), although I suspect I might have got more definitive results if I'd done the search in Polish.